# Create new array from existing nested values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following array:

```
 [ 
   { "publication": "" }, 
   { "publication": [ 
       { "author": "Author of Paper", 
         "journal": "Journal of Paper", 
         "title": "Title of Paper" 
       }, 
       { "author": "Author Paper", 
         "journal": "Journal Paper", 
         "title": "Title Paper" } ] }, 
   { "publication": "" }
 ]
```

I would like to discard the empty entries and push all entries into a new array with the following output

```
[
1: {
"author": "Author of Paper",
"title": "Title of Paper"
"journal": "Journal of Paper"
},
2: {
"author": "Author of Paper",
"title": "Title of Paper"
"journal": "Journal of Paper"
}
]
```

How would I achieve this?

I have attempted something of the following:

```
     var container = {};
     users = users.map(function(obj) {

 for(i = 0; i < publications.length; ++i) {
 container[i] 
         = { 
            "author": obj.author,
            "title": obj.title,
             "journal": obj.journal,
           }; 
}
```

Comment: Your desired result is expressed in invalid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Inside reduce first check if the value is truthy than only add it to final output.

```js
let arr =  [{ "publication": "" },{ "publication": [{ "author": "Author of Paper", "journal": "Journal of Paper", "title": "Title of Paper" }, { "author": "Author Paper", "journal": "Journal Paper", "title": "Title Paper" } ] }, { "publication": "" } ]
 
let output = arr.reduce((op, {publication} ) => {
  if(publication){
    op.push(...publication)
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the upcoming [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a replacement for falsy values.

```js
var array = [{ publication: "" }, { publication: [{ author: "Author of Paper", journal: "Journal of Paper", title: "Title of Paper" }, { author: "Author Paper", journal: "Journal Paper", title: "Title Paper" }] }, { publication: "" }],
    result = array.flatMap(({ publication }) => publication || []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
[/*....*/].reduce((acc, {publication}) => acc.includes(publication) ?  acc : [...acc, publication], [])
```